# Как заставить корректно работать несколько Sidebars в Semantic UI?

Tags: html, jquery, css, html5

Добрый день! Не могу заставить работать несколько панелей корректно.
Semantic-UI частично отправляет сайдбары внутрь контейнера #Pusher

Я не хочу, чтобы toolbar входил в Pusher и правая панель.
Это происходит после нажатия кнопки Toggle для левого сайдбара.

```html
<div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#middle-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Skip to main content</a>
</div>
<div id="toolbar" class="toolbar overlay-displace-top clearfix toolbar-processed">
...
</div>
<div class="ui left sidebar vertical inverted menu overlay" id="ls">
...
 </div>


<div class="ui right sidebar vertical inverted menu overlay" id="ls">
...
</div>
<div class="ui fixed top attached inverted menu">
...
</div>


<div id="page">
...
</div>
```

После нажатия кнопки:

```html
<div class="ui left sidebar vertical inverted menu overlay" id="ls">
...
 </div>
<div id="pusher">


  <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#middle-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Skip to main content</a>
  </div>


  <div id="toolbar" class="toolbar overlay-displace-top clearfix toolbar-processed">
  ...
  </div>


  <div class="ui right sidebar vertical inverted menu overlay" id="ls">
  ...
  </div>


</div>


<div class="ui fixed top attached inverted menu">
...
</div>
```

Каким образом я могу задать струкутуру, чтобы все заработало, как следует?

Спасибо!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что на английский StackOverflow

Comment: Please use http://stackoverflow.com for questions in English. Thank you.